# How do you change the font of `Plots.text()` in julia?

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

I am using the `Plots.text` function from the `Plots.jl` package to annotate points in my plot. It appears that changing the `plot(..., fontfamily="Computer Modern")` does note seem to have an effect on these annotations.

Answer (score 1):

`Plots.text` creates a text object including styling information. It is therefore necessary to change the font directly

```
Plots.text("abcde", "Arial")
```

seems to work